# SSRS expression not working properly

Tags: reporting-services, expression, ssrs-2012

I have one expression in my `SSRS` report which use to display currency data in the report. When there is no data `NULL` in the particular row it should display $0. However, it is displaying `#Error`.

```
=IIF(Fields!Value.Value="Nothing","$0",FormatCurrency(Fields!Value.Value,0))
```

I tried with `IsNothing` function as well but getting same result.

Comment: Does it throw when you turn the expression around --> =IIF(!IsNothing(Fields!Value.Value),FormatCurrency(Fields!Value.Value,0),"$0")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the quotes off Nothing..

```
=IIF(Fields!Value.Value=Nothing,"$0",FormatCurrency(Fields!Value.Value,0))
```

Comment: Is there a DBNull in the SSRS expression context?